# Assign colors for plotting based on data

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot a scatterplot graph using 13 categories, but when I do it will only give me 8 colors and repeat the same color.

How can I assign 13 different colors based on the category?

```
plot(combi$solar, combi$aetchem, col=combi$biome, pch=16, xlab="Solar",ylab="AET Chem")
legend("topleft", legend, unique(combi$biome), col=unique(combi$biome), title="Biomes", ncol=3, pch=16)
```

I'd like to see a scatterplot graph with plotted with 13 different colors based on the category(biome) and matching color legend.

Answer (score 0):

You could create yourself a vector with color names (as many as you want)

```
colors = c("red","black","blue","yellow","green","purple","pink","brown","darkgreen","grey",
  "orange","cyan","darkblue")
```

Then, give the parameter

```
col = colors[as.numeric(as.character.factor(combi$biome))]
```